# Populate DropdownList using EF Core (from another model)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have 2 classes.    `Photos` and `Albums`
I need to include the Album names in my Photos/Create  View  and create Dropdowns for Album names.

The model in my View Photo/Create is : `ImageViewModel`

How can I get it?

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5), MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private DateTime? dateCreated = null;
    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get => dateCreated.HasValue ? this.dateCreated.Value : DateTime.Now;
        set => this.dateCreated = value;
    }

    public virtual List<PhotoAlbums> PhotoAlbums { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoAlbums
{
    public int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
}

public  class Photo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public string AlbumNames { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PhotoAlbums> PhotoAlbums { get; set; }
}


public class ImageViewModel
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ImageViewModel()
    {
        _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; }

    public string Albumname { get; set; }
    public string ImageSrc
    {
        get
        {
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
            string imgSrc = String.Format("data:image;base64,{0}", base64); //"data:image/png;base64,{0}"
            return imgSrc;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would create a drop down list of albums. Good luck.

Try adding an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to your ImageViewModel for your DropdownList of Albums.

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public ImageViewModel()
    {
        _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; }

    public string Albumname { get; set; }
    public string ImageSrc
    {
        get
        {
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
            string imgSrc = String.Format("data:image;base64,{0}", base64); //"data:image/png;base64,{0}"
            return imgSrc;
        }
    }

    public int AlbumId{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Albums { get; set; } //you dropdown
}
```

Then in your controller, hydrate the DropdownList of Albums.

```
List<Album> albums = null; //get your albums from _context
var model = new ImageViewModel();
model.Albums = new SelectList(albums, "Id", "Name");
//hydrate the rest of your model..
```

Finally in your view, display your DropdownList of Albums.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AlbumId, Model.Albums })
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer helps you out, please accept it as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Model In View Page:

```
  @model IEnumerable<ImageViewModel>
```

then Generate DropDown:

```
<select id="dropdowntipo">
    <option value="0">Select Item</option>

    @{
      foreach(var item in Model)
      {
        <option value= "@item.Value">@item.DisplayText</option>
      }
    }

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `ViewBag` to pass data from controller to view. Assume you have `Albums` table in your dbContext:

```
public DbSet<Album> Albums{ get; set; }
```

1.Create Action:

```
public class PhotosController : Controller
{
    private  ApplicationDbContext _context { get; set; }
    publicPhotosController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new ImageViewModel();
        ViewBag.AlbumList = _context.Albums.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

2.Create View:

```
@model ImageViewModel
@*other view code*@

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Albumname , new SelectList(ViewBag.AlbumList,"Name","Name"))
```